# rails 4 uninitialized constant AuthController::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to have a login form in my rails applicaiton but getting an error like

```
NameError in AuthController#login
uninitialized constant AuthController::User
```

Here is my view

```
<%= form_for @users, do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Username' %>
<%= end %>
```

My controller is

```
def login
    #@users = User.all I 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use any variable in your view, you must assign/define it in action def of controller page.

You can use for an empty value-

```
    def login
      @user = User.new
      .......
    end
```

As for login you have no pre assigned values (which is used for edit form), you must use an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you would have to define the user and then your form will be called for that particular object:

```
def login  
    @user = User.new
    .....
end

<%= form_for @user, do |f| %> ....
```